# Speeding Up ETL DB2 to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, etl

I came across this blog post when looking for a quicker way of importing data from a DB2 database to SQL Server 2008.

http://blog.stevienova.com/2009/05/20/etl-method-fastest-way-to-get-data-from-db2-to-microsoft-sql-server/

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following:

***3) Create a BULK Insert task, and load up the file that the execute process task created. (note you have to create a .FMT file for fixed with import. I create a .NET app to load the FDF file (the transfer description) which will auto create a .FMT file for me, and a SQL Create statement as well – saving time and tedious work)***

I've got the data in a TXT file and a separate FDF with the details of the table structure. How do I combine them to create a suitable .FMT file?

Comment: Have you looked at the MSDN docs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to create the suitable .FMT files.

Instead I ended up creating replica tables from the source DB2 system in SQL Server and ensured that that column order was the same as what was coming out from the IBM File Transfer Utility.

Using an Excel sheet to control what File Transfers/Tables should be loaded, allowing me to enable/disable as I please, along with a For Each Loop in SSIS I've got a suitable solution to load multiple tables quickly from our DB2 system.